# What is the difference between state and activity of activity diagram in UML?

Tags: uml

Now I'm learning UML. While I'm trying to draw an activity diagram, I find two things, the state and activity . What's the difference between those two things? I try to find those in google but don't get a clear explanation. Can somebody explain me with simple explanation about those?

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Edit :

btw, I found those two things in IBM rational rose.

Comment: Which version of UML are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The state is not used in activity diagram, but can be used in state-chart diagram. Whereas the activity which can be used to describe the work flow of the model. Which resembles activities performed by the machine technically or non technically (software or other works).